# "Sarva Dharman Parityejya Mamekam Sharanam Vraja..." in Shiva Gita?

Tags: scripture, shiva, history, rama, gita

One of the most important verse of Bhagvad Gita is the 66th verse of 18th Chapter where Lord states as:

> सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज |
>   अहं त्वां सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुच: || 66||
>   sarva-dharmān parityajya mām ekaṁ śharaṇaṁ vraja
>   ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo mokṣhayiṣhyāmi mā śhuchaḥ
>   
>   Abandon all varieties of dharmas and simply surrender unto me alone. I shall liberate you from all sinful reactions; do not fear.

[**Shiva Gita**](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/shivagiitaa.html?lang=sa) is a part of Padma Purana (Uttara Khanda). 

*Just as Arjuna is distressed in Bhagvad Gita and Krishna instructs Arjuna. In the similar way Rama is distressed due to loss of his wife Sita in the Dandakaranya Vana. Maharshi Agastya comes there and instructs Rama to do Pashupata Vratam. Then Rama performs it as per instructions by Agastya and then Lord Shiva manifests there and teaches him Gita. This forms the origin of Shiva Gita.*

Since we do not find this story in Valmiki Ramayana it is likely that this occurred in Ramayana of previous Kalpas. 

**So, are there any verses in Shiva Gita which is same as Bhagvad Gita 18.66 or verses which gives the same message...?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in the 14th chapter of Shiva Gita, the Gita message goes as:

> श्रीराम उवाच ॥
>   
>   भगवञ्छ्रवणे नैव प्रवर्तन्ते जनाः कथम् ।
>   वेदशास्त्रार्थसम्पन्ना यज्वानः सत्यवादिनः ॥ ३५॥
>   शृण्वन्तोऽपि तथात्मानं जानते नैव केचन ।
>   ज्ञात्वापि मन्वते मिथ्या किमेतत्तव मायया ॥ ३६॥
>  
>  
>   Sri Rama spoke:
>  
>   Oh Lord when one can realise Atma swarupa from methods like Shravana then why do not persons expert in Vedas and Shastras get Pravritta in this path? And some can't even know Atman after hearing too and some while knowing also call it false. Why is it so? Is it your Maya?
>
> श्रीभगवानुवाच ॥
>   
>   एवमेव महाबाहो नात्र कार्या विचारणा ।
>   दैवी ह्येषा गुणमयी मम माया दुरत्यया ॥ ३७॥
>   मामेव ये प्रपद्यन्ते मायामेतां तरन्ति ते ।
>   अभक्ता ये महाबाहो मम श्रद्धा विवर्जिताः ॥ ३८॥
>   फलं कामयमानास्ते चैहिकामुष्मिकादिकम् ।
>   क्षयिष्ण्वल्पं सातिशयं यतः कर्मफलं मतम् ॥ ३९॥
>   तदविज्ञाय कर्माणि ये कुर्वन्ति नराधमाः ।
>   मातुः पतन्ति ते गर्भे मृत्योर्वक्त्रे पुनः पुनः ॥ ४०॥
>   
>   Lord Spoke:
>  
>   Oh Mahabaho it is as you spoke, there is no doubt in it. My maya is very hard to overcome. Only those who come to my refugee can get rid of this maya. Those who are not devoted to me and do not have faith in me they get fruits as per their karma. Without knowing me when the fruits of their Karma gets finished they again get birth in womb of mother.
>
> नानायोनिषु जातस्य देहिनो यस्यकस्यचित् ।
>   कोटिजन्मार्जितैः पुण्यैर्मयि भक्तिः प्रजायते ॥ ४१॥
>   स एव लभते ज्ञानं मद्भक्तः श्रद्धयान्वितः ।
>   नान्यकर्माणि कुर्वाणो जन्मकोटिशतैरपि ॥ ४२॥
>   ततः सर्वं परित्यज्य मद्भक्तिं समुदाहर ।
>   **सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज ॥ ४३॥
>
>   अहं त्वा सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुचः ।**
>   यत्करोषि यदश्नासि यज्जुहोषि ददासि यत् ॥ ४४॥
>   यत्तपस्यसि राम त्वं तत्कुरुष्व मदर्पणम् ।
>   ततः परतरा नास्ति भक्तिर्मयि रघूत्तम ॥ ४५॥
>   
>   A rare person accumulating virtue from millions of births only gets devoted to me. Only those having Shraddha on me get my knowledge, other doing Karmas for millions of births also can't know me. Therefore abandon everything and be devoted to me. **Abandon all varieties of dharmas and simply surrender unto me alone. I shall liberate you from all sinful reactions; do not fear.** Whatever karma you do, whatever food you eat and whatever oblations you give, whatever austerity you perform offer everything to me. O Rama there is nothing Superior to my devotion.