# Is Shiva Sankalpa Suktam also a Khila Sukta of RigVeda?

Tags: scripture, shiva, vedas, rig-veda, hymn

Khila Suktas of RigVeda are those Suktas which are associated only in Baskala Shakha of RigVeda and not in Sakala Shakha. For eg. Sri Suktam of RigVeda is also a Khila Sukta.

Shiva Sankalpam Sukta is a part of Vedas. In the 34th chapter of Vajasaneyi Samhita Shukla Yajurveda first six mantras form Shiva Sankalpa Suktam. They all end with the line:

> **तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पम् अस्तु ।** 
>   tanme manaha: ShivaSankalpam Aastu
>   
>   May my mind do Sankalpa of Shiva.

However [this website](http://ahymsin.org/main/swami-veda-bharati/shiva-sankalpa-sukta.html) states that:

> The 33rd chapter of Kanva recension of Yajur-veda contains only the first mantra.  The 34th chapter of the Vajasaneya recension has six. These are the most well known. **Less known is the apocryphal version in the Khila-suktas of Rg-veda (Khila-sukta 33), containing 26 mantras.**

**So, Is Shiva Sankalpa Sukta also a part of Khila Sukta of RigVeda?**

Particularly I'm interested in the verse 14 of the Hymn:

> On the charming peak of Kailasha mountain is the home temple of the Peace-creator Shiva; gods rejoice in that. May such my mind be of beautiful and divine resolves, filled with Shiva-thoughts. -14

As a sidenote, Srikantha Shivacharya in his Brahma Sutra Bhasya 3.2.35 also quotes Shiva Sankalpa:

> **Even in the Siva-Sankalpa, He is declared to have faces on all sides.** In the Atharvasiras, the Paramesvara is said to have many faces, feet, and so on. He is said to be associated with the Universe as an integral part of His being : 
>   "This Maya, indeed, as Prakriti, man should know and the possessor of Maya as the Mahesvara. All this universe is pervaded by that which forms a limb of His."

So, can someone post here Shiva Sankalpa Khila Sukta of RigVeda in Sanskrit? At least I want to confirm whether Shiva Sankalpa Sukta also forms a part of Khila Sukta of RigVeda or not?

Comment: His name is Srikantha Shivacharya, and his commentary is called the Srikantha Bhashya.

Comment: Could you tell me where in Brhaddevata the 26 verses are mentioned?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, Shiva Sankalpa Sukta is also a Khila Sukta of RigVeda. In the archive site we can find it in the book [Rig-Veda Sayana Commentary Part 4](https://ia800808.us.archive.org/3/items/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart4/rv_sayanabhasya_part4.pdf) in the Khilani section where Khila Suktas of RigVeda are given. Shiva Sankalpa Sukta is as:

> येनेदं भूतं भुवनं भविष्यत् परिगृहिततममृतेन सर्वम् ।
>   येन यज्ञस्तायते सप्त होता तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 1
>   
>   येन कर्माण्यपसो मनीषिणो यज्ञे कृण्वन्ति विदथेषु धीराः ।
>   यदपूर्वं यक्षमन्तः प्रजानां तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 2
>   
>   यत्प्रज्ञानमुत चेतो धृतिश्च यज्ज्योतिरन्तरमृतं प्रजासु ।
>   यस्मान्न ऋते किं चन कर्म क्रियते तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 3
>   
>   यज्जाग्रतो दूरमुदैति दैवं तदु सुप्तस्य तथैवैति।
>   दूरंगमं ज्योतिषां ज्योतिरेकं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 4
>   
>   यस्मिन्नृचः साम यजूंषि यस्मिन् प्रतिष्ठिता रथनाभाविवाराः।
>   यस्मिश्चित्तं सर्वमोतं प्रजानां तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 5
>   
>   सुसारथिरश्वानिव यन्मनुष्यान्नेनीयतेऽभीशुभिर्वाजिन इव ।
>   हृत्प्रतिष्ठं यदजिरं जविष्ठं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 6
>   
>   यदत्र षष्ठं त्रिशतं शरीरं यज्ञस्य गुह्यं नवनाभमाद्यम् ।
>   दश पञ्च त्रिशतं यत्परं च तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 7
>   
>   य पञ्चपञ्चा दशतं शतं च सहस्रं च नियुतं न्यर्बुदं च ।
>   ते यज्ञचित्तेष्टकात्तं शरीरं तन्मे मनः शिव संकल्पमस्तु ।। 8
>   
>   वेदाहमेतं पुरुषं महान्तमादित्यवर्णं तमस परस्तात् ।
>   तस्ये योनि परिपश्यन्ति धीरास्तन्मे मनः शिव संकल्पमस्तु ।। 9
>   
>   येन कर्माणि प्रचरन्ति धीरा विप्रा वाचा मनसा कर्मणा च ।
>   यस्यान्वितमनु सं यन्ति प्राणिनस्तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 10
>   
>   ये मनो हृदयं ये च देवा ये अन्तरीक्षे बहुदा चरन्ति ।
>   ये श्रोत्रं चक्षुषी संचरन्ति तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 11
>   
>   येन द्यौरुग्रा पृथिवी चान्तरिक्षं ये पर्वताः प्रदिशो दिशश्च ।
>   येनेदं जगद्व्याप्तं प्रजानां तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 12
>   
>   येनेदं सर्वं जगतो बभूवुर्ये देवा अपि महतो जातवेदाः ।
>   तदिवाग्निस्तपसो ज्योतिरेकं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 13
>   
>   अचिन्तयं चाप्रमेयं च व्यक्ताव्यक्तपरः च यत् ।
>   सूक्ष्मात्सूक्ष्मतरं ज्ञानं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 14
>   
>   अस्ति विनाशथित्वा सर्वमिदं नास्ति पुनस्तथैव द्दृष्टं ध्रुवम् ।
>   अस्ति नास्ति हितं मध्यमं पदं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 15
>   
>   अस्ति नास्ति विपरीतो प्रवादोऽस्ति नास्ति सर्वं वा इदं गुह्यम् ।
>   अस्ति नास्ति परात्परो यत्परं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 16
>   
>   परात्परतरं यश्च तत्पराश्चैव यत्परम् ।
>   तत्परात्परतोऽज्ञेयं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 17
>   
>   परात्परतरो ब्रह्मा तत्परात्परतो हरिः ।
>   तत्परात्परतो ईश तन्मे मन शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 18
>   
>   गोभिर्जुष्टो धनेन ह्यायुषा च बलेन च ।
>   प्रजया पशुभिः पुष्कलाद्यं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 19
>   
>   प्रयतः प्रणवो नित्यं परमं पुरुषोत्तमम् ।
>   ओंकारं परमात्मानं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 20
>   
>   यो वै वेदादिषु गायत्री सर्वव्यापिमहेश्वरात् ।
>   तद्विरुक्तं यथाद्वैश्यं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 21
>   
>   यो वै वेद महादेवं परमं पुरुषोत्तमम् ।
>   यः सर्व यस्य चित्सर्व तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 22
>   
>   योऽसौ सर्वेषु वेदेषु पठते ह्यज ईश्वरः ।
>   अकायो निर्गुणोऽध्यात्मा तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 23
>   
>   कैलासशिखरे रम्ये शंकरस्य शुभे गृहे ।
>   देवतास्तत्र मोदन्ति तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 24
>   
>   कैलासशिखराभासा हिमवद्गिरिसंस्थिताः ।
>   नीलकण्ठं त्रिनेत्रं च तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 25
>   
>   आब्रह्मस्तम्बपर्यन्तं त्रैलोक्य स चराचरम् ।
>   उत्पातितं जगद्व्याप्तं तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु।। 26
>   
>   य इमं शिवसंकल्पं सदा ध्यायन्ति ब्राह्मणाः ।
>   ते परं मोक्षं गमिष्यन्ति तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 27

Regarding the quotations of Shiva Sankalpa Khila Sukta; Srikantha Shivacharya has quoted it in his Brahma Sutra Bhasya 4.3.18. The verse which he has quoted is:

> परात्परतरो ब्रह्मा तत्परात्परतो हरिः ।
>   तत्परात्परतो ईश तन्मे मन शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 18
>  
>   Greater than the great is Brahma, greater still than that great one is Hari, even greater than this one is Isha.

Also in the footnote of the same book it is written Medhatithi (commentator on Manu Smriti) has written as 'खिलादि श्रीसुक्तशिवसंकल्पादिनी श्राद्धे ब्राह्मणान् श्रवयेत्' or 'Brahmana should listen to Khila Suktas like Sri Sukta and Shiva Sankalpa Sukta with faith.' while commenting on Manu 3.232. Similarly Manu Smriti also in 11.251 states 'शिवसंकल्प पापहरमिती...' '(chanting) Shiva Sankalpa destroys (this) sin.'

Regarding the references in Puranas Agni Purana in chapter 259 while stating about benefits of Rig-Veda mantras also state about Shiva Sankalpa Sukta as 'yenedamiti' hymn. Linga Purana also state Parashar worshipping Shiva using Shiva Sankalpa Sukta '...जप्त्वा त्वरितरुद्रं च शिवसंकल्पमेव च...।।' /'...he worshipped chanting Tvarita Rudra as well as Shiva Sankalpa...' which I discuss [here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12185/which-mantras-should-be-recited-to-properly-worship-lord-rudra/16878#16878)

I also discuss some quotes of Shiva Sankalpa Sukta in my answer [here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18838/is-lord-shiva-clearly-noted-as-prathama-purusha-in-any-veda/18842#18842) Similarly regarding the quote which I mentioned in question it is as:

> कैलासशिखरे रम्ये शंकरस्य शुभे गृहे ।
>   देवतास्तत्र मोदन्ति तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 24
>  
>   **In the summit of Kailash is the beautiful home of Shankara. Gods rejoice in that, May my mind be filled with Shiva thoughts.**

Comment: By the way, I wonder how the Shiva Sankalpa Sukta is used in Yagnas.  By the way, do you know what Mandala of the Rig Veda it's associated with? (Khila Suktas are associated with some Mandala in the Bashkala Shakha.)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It was in the RigVeda Samhita 10.166... The book also quotes Brihaddevata 8.69 for it...

Comment: Oh ok, the whole reason I wanted to know the Mandala was so I could locate it in Shaunaka's Brihaddevata.  Here's the relevant excerpt: https://ia802607.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/2/items/brhaddevataattr02saunuoft/brhaddevataattr02saunuoft_jp2.zip&file=brhaddevataattr02saunuoft_jp2/brhaddevataattr02saunuoft_0332.jp2&scale=4&rotate=0 The Devata is given as Manasa or mind.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan yeah I already knew devata through Vajasaneyi 34th chapter....

Comment: I see that there are 39 verses listed in Siva Sankalpam that is recited during Mahanyasam. Is there a commentary of these 39 verses available anywhere? If not, can you provide some?

Comment: Can you provide a translation for the above hymn?

Comment: @Tezz where can find Shiva Sankalpa Sukta in Yajur Veda? Kindly share its location. Pranam

Comment: @SanatanaDhara 34th chapter of Vajasaneyi Samhita..

Comment: Namaḥ Śivāya, There are only 15 śloka in 4th chapter, 3 section of Brahmasūtra bhāṣya of Śrikānth Acharya copy which I've. Can u pls share the link of commentary translation which you have or exact verse after rechecking. Thanks

Comment: Nvm i found it.

Answer (score 9):

Yes Khilanis are the section of appendices associated with Bhaskāla shakha of Rigveda. Sri suktam, Ratri suktam, Medha suktam and Shiva sankalpa suktam are the 4 khila suktas of Bhaskāla shakha of Rigveda.

These suktas are separated as khilanis because of the reason that they vary in the metres of chandas with respect to early Rigvedic sanskrit and even few other gramatical variations.

Rigvedic Shakhāla shakha was civilized at 11th century BCE whereas these khilanis belonged to the Vedic mantra period in between (10th Century BCE) and these khilanis are older than Yajurvedic mantra period.

Shiva sankalpa suktam of Shukla yajurveda which appears in kanva recension part of vajasaneyi samhitha also consists of first 6 mantras of this particular Vedic text.

There are 26 mantras in this suktam which belongs to brhadevata samhitha which comes under the saunaka recension 8.69 of Rigveda. There are some disputes that Sri suktam which also is a khila sukta is been added with few verses at later times but this Shiva sankalpa suktam's 26 verses are very authentically present in Brhadevata samhitha of Saunaka recension of Bhaskāla shakha of Rigveda.

Medhātithi - The famous interpreter of 6th century BCE who wrote bhashyas on Manu smrithi and Yagnavalkya smrithi also addresses this suktam. In his bhashya on Manu smrithi 3.232 he states:-

खिलादि श्रीसुक्तशिवसंकल्पादिनी श्राद्धे ब्राह्मणान् श्रवयेत्
Brahmanas should always contemplate on Khila suktas like Sri sukta and Shiva sankalpa.

Apart from that you can find this sukta's complete 26 verses in the Rigveda bhashya of Uvvata acharya of 11th century, Sayanacarya of 13th century and even Maridhara swami of 16th century.

In fact this is one of the hidden gem in Vedas which dominantly explains Shiva's supremacy.

Comment: Could you tell me where in Brhaddevata the 26 verses are mentioned.