# Prayers for Mind?

Tags: mantras, brahman, stotra, mind

Are there any Vedic Prayer, Mantra, Stotra for/on Mind

```
Śukla Yajurveda 34.1
Śukla Yajurveda 34.2
Śukla Yajurveda 34.3
Śukla Yajurveda 34.4
Śukla Yajurveda 34.5
Śukla Yajurveda 34.6
```

Can someone write this in Sanskrit.. Taken from [Hindupedia](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Ideals_and_Values/The_Science_of_Mind_and_Sense_Organs)

Please write If you know any more on this..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visit [What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277) to find and read scriptures.
You can easily read/find Vedas in original Sanskrit at [Sanskrit Wikisource](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A9%E0%A5%AA), [Vedic Reserve site](https://vedicreserve.miu.edu/yajur_veda.htm), [Snskrit web](http://www.sanskritweb.net/yajurveda/) etc. sources.

Yes, the mantras you quoted is known as **Shiva Sankalpa Sukta** or sometimes "Shiva Sankalpa Upanishad".

Qutoing Sanskrit from [sanskritdocuments.org](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/shivasankalpopanishad.html) and English translation from [here](https://fivefoldpathmission.us/Documents/Shiva_Sankalpa_Sukta_English.pdf).

> > यज्जाग्र॑तो दू॒रमु॒दैति॒ दैवं॒ तदु॑ सु॒प्तस्य॒ तथै॒वैति॑  ।
> > दू॒रं॒ग॒मं ज्योति॑षां॒ ज्योति॒रेकं॒ **तन्मे॒ मनः॑ शि॒वसं॑कल्पमस्तु** ॥ १॥   
> > yajjāgra̍to dū̱ramu̱daiti̱ daiva̱ṃ tadu̍ su̱ptasya̱ tathai̱vaiti̍  .
> > dū̱ra̱ṃga̱maṃ jyoti̍ṣā̱ṃ jyoti̱reka̱ṃ tanme̱ mana̍ḥ śi̱vasa̍ṃkalpamastu .. 1..
>
> That mind which in the waking state through the means of the senses roams through this world, and which in the dream state roams through many worlds  and in the state of deep sleep returns to its origin,that far wanderer, that light of knowledge **my mind, may you have good intentions**.

> > येन॒ कर्मा॑ण्य॒पसो॑ मनी॒षिणो॑ य॒ज्ञे कृ॒ण्वन्ति॑ वि॒दथे॑षु धीराः॑ ।
> > यद॑पू॒र्वं य॒क्षम॒न्तः प्र॒जानां॒ *तन्मे॒ मनः॑ शि॒वसं॑कल्पमस्तु* ॥ २॥ 
> > yena̱ karmā̍ṇya̱paso̍ manī̱ṣiṇo̍ ya̱jñe kṛ̱ṇvanti̍ vi̱dathe̍ṣu dhīrā̍ḥ .
> > yada̍pū̱rvaṃ ya̱kṣama̱ntaḥ pra̱jānā̱ṃ tanme̱ mana̍ḥ śi̱vasa̍ṃkalpamastu .. 2..
>
> The means by which a man who wants to do good, whose senses are stilled and who is wise and diligent becomes proficient in yajnas another karmas established by the shastras and also that which is the principal and most revered of the means of knowledge, *my mind, may you have good intentions*.

> > यत्प्र॒ज्ञान॑मु॒त चेतो॒ धृति॑श्च॒ यज्ज्योति॑र॒न्तर॒मृतं॑ प्र॒जासु॑ ।
> > यस्मा॒न्न ऋ॒ते किंच॒ न कर्म॑ क्रि॒यते॒ *तन्मे॒ मनः॑ शि॒वसं॑कल्पमस्तु* ॥ ३॥ 
> > yatpra̱jñāna̍mu̱ta ceto̱ dhṛti̍śca̱ yajjyoti̍ra̱ntara̱mṛta̍ṃ pra̱jāsu̍ .
> > yasmā̱nna ṛ̱te kiṃca̱ na karma̍ kri̱yate̱ tanme̱ mana̍ḥ śi̱vasa̍ṃkalpamastu .. 3..
>
> That mind which disregarding the demands of the senses is focused on knowledge alone, and which knows the elements of the universe, constant and immortal, which lives inside a man but is capable of illuminating what is outside, without whom no actions are possible, *my mind, may you have good intentions.*

> > येने॒दं भू॒तं भुव॑नं भवि॒ष्यत् परि॑गृहीतम॒मृते॑न॒ सर्व॑म् ।
> > येन॑ य॒ज्ञस्ता॒यते॑ स॒प्तहो॑ता॒ *तन्मे॒ मनः॑ शि॒वसं॑कल्पमस्तु* ॥ ४॥ 
> > yene̱daṃ bhū̱taṃ bhuva̍naṃ bhavi̱ṣyat pari̍gṛhītama̱mṛte̍na̱ sarva̍m .
> > yena̍ ya̱jñastā̱yate̍ sa̱ptaho̍tā̱ tanme̱ mana̍ḥ śi̱vasa̍ṃkalpamastu .. 4..
>
> That exists until mukti, that knows past, present and future,through which the yogis obtain immortality, and through which the yajna with seven priests is performed, *my mind, may you have good intentions.*

> > यस्मि॒न्नृचः॒ साम॒ यजू॑ꣳषि॒ यस्मि॒न् प्रति॑ष्ठिता रथना॒भावि॑वा॒राः ।
> > यस्मि॑ꣳश्चि॒तꣳ सर्व॒मोतं॑ प्र॒जानां॒ *तन्मे॒ मनः॑ शि॒वसं॑कल्पमस्तु* ॥ ५॥ 
> > yasmi̱nnṛca̱ḥ sāma̱ yajū̍gͫṣi̱ yasmi̱n prati̍ṣṭhitā rathanā̱bhāvi̍vā̱rāḥ .
> > yasmi̍gͫści̱tagͫ sarva̱mota̍ṃ pra̱jānā̱ṃ tanme̱ mana̍ḥ śi̱vasa̍ṃkalpamastu .. 5..
>
> That mind which is the hub of the chariot wheel whose spokes are the Rks, Yajus, and Samans and whose axle is knowledge and which is pulled this way and that by the sense-horses, *my mind may you be of good intentions.*

> > सु॒षा॒र॒थिरश्वा॑निव॒ यन्म॑नु॒ष्या॒न्नेनी॒यते॒ऽभीशु॑भिर्वा॒जिन॑ इव ।
> > हृ॒त्प्रति॑ष्ठं॒ यद॑जि॒रं जवि॑ष्ठं॒ *तन्मे॒ मनः॑ शि॒वसं॑कल्पमस्तु* ॥ ६॥ 
> > su̱ṣā̱ra̱thiraśvā̍niva̱ yanma̍nu̱ṣyā̱nnenī̱yate̱'bhīśu̍bhirvā̱jina̍ iva .
> > hṛ̱tprati̍ṣṭha̱ṃ yada̍ji̱raṃ javi̍ṣṭha̱ṃ tanme̱ mana̍ḥ śi̱vasa̍ṃkalpamastu .. 6..
>
> Just as a good charioteer makes the horses run according to his commands so they go where he wants them too, so too the mind can guide a man towards his desire and by restraining animal instincts lead to that dweller in the heart who is immortal and free of turmoil, *my mind may you have good intentions.*

You may also find another English translation at [sacred-texts.com](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk34.htm) and Hindi interpretation [here](http://www.vyakhya.org/shivasankalpasukta/sss-1/). Some books e.g.[this one is available on Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/shivasankalpasuktaswamimahesanandagiri_202004_425_U/page/n5/mode/2up) are available with detailed explanation.

Note that these verses are found in Rigveda. Visit [Is Shiva Sankalpa Suktam also a Khila Sukta of RigVeda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17644/277)