# Mention of Liberation in Vedas

Tags: vedas, moksha

Does vedas mention the ways for Liberation ? And I mean specifically Vedas but not others as some Puranas, and  texts like Gita (Bhagavadgita) mentioned ways of liberation.

Comment: Also see [Where does Rig Veda say that Shiva is the God who grants Moksha?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12019/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks, I will look in to those mentions